# Is there any way I can add image in bytes to pdf in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, io, fpdf

I generated some plots in pandas and save it in BytesIO streams, and then I want to add it to a pdf page, then send out the pdf file as attachment in email:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from fpdf import FPDF

fig = plt.figure()
...
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(buf.getvalue(), type='PNG')
buf.close()
```

But this is not working, with the following error reported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXX.py", line 166, in send_email
    pdf.image(buf.getvalue(), type='PNG')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 971, in image
    info=self._parsepng(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1769, in _parsepng
    if name.startswith("http://") or name.startswith("https://"):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

I want to solve this purely in memory and not to save image files locally. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: The [image](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html) method wants a "name" (filename or URL), not `bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use bytes instead of a file ...

In my case i have an MSSQL query that contains images as a binary string. And i want to use them directly, without saving multiple image-files. So i was looking for a solution.

What we need:

```
pip install fpdf2
```

Then import IO and FPDF2 into your python 3.x file:

```
import io
from fpdf import FPDF
```

A look into the [image_parsing.py](https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/blob/master/fpdf/image_parsing.py) of the fpdf2-repository on Github shows that fpdf2 can work with binary objects too. No real image-file needed.

With [BytesIO from io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) we can create a binary object out of our bytes string.

We name the binary object 'picture' and place it as our image into the PDF page.

```
import io
from fpdf import FPDF

# create bytes object of the image data
picture = io.BytesIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")

# set page to portrait A4 and positioning in mm
pdf = FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")

# create a page
pdf.add_page()

# insert image
# on position: x=10mm, y=10mm
# size: width=50mm hight=auto
pdf.image(picture,10,10,50)

# create PDF file
pdf.output("fpdf_test.pdf")
```

I hope this is helpful to some people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to solve this purely in memory and not to save image files locally."*

No you should not do that. UNLESS you save a PDF in memory on a massive memory file drive. Most devices use the file system for extended memory so its a lot easier to use the physical file system rather than build a custom one in your very precious memory resources. Small files may work if your system has a Memory stream File System to use **filenames** with.

A PDF is a resource hog since you MUST

1. save the image as a naturally compressed image object
2. decompress in that precious memory a reprex to inject as a PDF image one way or another
3. usually duplicated and re-expanded to be visible on screen
4. then the image data needs to be encoded into a deflated stream object
5. then the new flated image needs to be written to the pdf as a partial file object with a hardcoded decimal address in a PDF file System.
6. then the object needs to be cataloged and indexed at the end of the physical file so the WHOLE PDF must also be expanded in memory.

... am I explaining why its simpler to just save down to drip feed cached file objects ? Rather than mess about using Gigabytes of RAM drives.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be a comment since it points out something they might not have thought about. However, it does not answer the question that was asked and the user might still want to pursue the question after considering the... RAMifications :)